# display variable value each n iterations with condition outside the loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

When I have to display the variable value every n iterations of a `for` loop I always do something along these lines:

```
for ii=1:1000
  if mod(ii,100)==0 
     display(num2str(ii))
  end
end
```

I was wondering if there is a way to move the `if` condition outside the loop in order to speed up the code. Or also if there is something different I could do.

Comment: Why you don't use just `display(ii)`, without converting it first to a string? this may save you some time

Comment: true. I usually do it to avoid the output to be in the form `ii= \n ii`

Comment: you should use `disp(ii)`

Comment: thx. didn't know `disp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested loops:

```
N = 1000;
n = 100;
for ii = n:n:N
    for k = ii-n+1:ii-1
        thingsToDo(k);
    end
    disp(ii)
    thingsToDo(ii);
end
```

where `thingsToDo()` get the relevant counter (if needed). This a little more messy, but can save a lot of `if` testing.

Comment: cool! I never thought to this. But I tried your code (after commenting `thingsToDo(k)`) and it ran in 0.005532 seconds. My code ran in 0.003336 seconds. I do not understand why though. At first sight I thought that your solution was faster

Comment: @shamalaia I tried it, and ran this for 100 times in both ways, and the nested one is significantly quicker in 0.3ms (p=0.006, but this is not a real valid statistical test). I'm not sure that it worth changing the code, it depends on how many iterations are in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the number of tested values is much larger than the number of printed values, I would not blame the if-statement. It may not seem this way at first, but printing is indeed a fairly complex task. A variable needs to be converted and sent to an output stream which is then printing in the terminal. In case you need to speed the code up, then reduce the amount of printed data.

Normally Matlab function takes vector inputs as well. This is the case for `disp` and `display` and does only take a single function call. Further, conversion to string is unnecessary before printing. Matlab should send the data to some kind of stream anyway (which may indeed take argument of type `char` but this is not the same char as Matlab uses), so this is probably just a waste of time. In addition to that `num2str` do a lot of things to ensure typesafe conversion. You already know that `display` is typesafe, so all these checks are redundant.

Try this instead,

```
q = (1:1000)'; % assuming q is some real data in your case
disp(q(mod(q,100)==0)) % this requires a single call to disp
```